# How to use stream filter and sum

Tags: java, java-stream

Is this way is the most efficient way to filter and sum using java streams?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = {23,43,56,97,32};
    int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().filter(e -> 35 < e).reduce(0,(a,b)->a+b);
}
```

What would a better alternative(if there) and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need or reason to box your stream - keep using the `IntStream` all the way:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array).filter(e -> 35 < e).sum();
```

Comment: Yes, not only is this easier to read, but also more efficient. You could also start the stream with `IntStream.of(array)` to make it more obvious that it is an `IntStream`.

Comment: @MalteHartwig it's the same thing underneath `IntStream.of(array)` still uses `Arrays.stream` and being obvious or not is opinion based

Comment: @MalteHartwig: I’d rather stay with `Arrays.stream(array)`, as this is streaming over an existing array instead of utilizing a *varargs* method that only happen to accept an existing array for compatibility with pre-Java 5 code…

Answer (score 2):

because `reduce` creates new Objects all the time, besides `Integer` and `int` are different things - summing would require un-boxing and boxing again.

The simpler and faster way would be to work off a `IntStream` specialization:

```
 Arrays.stream(array).filter(e -> 35 < e).sum();
```